# PHP preg_split delimiter pattern

Tags: design-patterns, delimiter

I have:

```
$str = ',7,5,3,'; 
preg_split( delimiter pattern, $str );
```

I need to get:

```
Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 )
```

Bit new to coding..

Thanks

Comment: You should use `explode()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php. `$str = explode( ',' , $str);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [explode](http://php.net/explode)

```
$str = ',7,5,3,';
$ary = explode(',', $str);
//Filter empty entries
$ary = array_filter($ary, 'strlen');
```

Code: http://ideone.com/iZ0bn8

Update: `preg_split` should be used if you have more complex delimiter patterns. In your case, you only have a single comma to split the string, so `explode` is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use trim and explode in that case

```
$str = ',7,5,3,'; 
$str = trim($str,',');

$arr = explode(',', $str);
print_r($arr); die();
```